# What is wrong with PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a database and I need to insert a new record there. I try to use PreparedStatement.

```
//Executing the INSERT query                
String addSql = "INSERT INTO savedforms (Patientfnr, Patientname) VALUES (?, ?)";       

//PreparedStatement for INSERT sql
java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt1 = connection.prepareStatement(addSql);

stmt1.setString(1, patientnumber);
stmt1.setString(2, patientname);


//Execute query 
stmt1.executeUpdate(addSql);
```

and get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1
```

how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
stmt1.executeUpdate(addSql);
```

to

```
stmt1.executeUpdate();
```

You've already set up your prepared statement, simply call [executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that as the method declares that it should not be called on PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

Check the javadoc for this kind of method